# How do I create a two-dimensional binary counting Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Create an array like this:

```
[[0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,1]
[0,0,1,0]
[0,0,1,1]
[0,1,0,0]
.
.
.
[1,1,1,1]]
```

I tried binary_repr() to create string of binary numbers and turn it into an array, but it cannot turn a whole array into binary representation.

Answer (score 2):

For numbers up to 255, use [`numpy.unpackbits`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html):

```
np.unpackbits(np.arange(16, dtype=np.uint8)[:,None], axis=1)[:, -4:]
```

*`[:, -4:]` is to keep the last 4 bits (out of 8).*

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

For number up to 65535 you can use the same logic breaking the number in two parts (first 8 bits, last 8 bits):

Here is an example with selected numbers (not a full range):

```
a = np.array([0,1,2,254,255,256,257,512,1024])[:,None]

out = np.c_[np.unpackbits((a>>8).astype(np.uint8), axis=1),
            np.unpackbits((a&255).astype(np.uint8), axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # 0
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],  # 1
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],  # 2
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],  # 254
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # 255
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # 256
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],  # 257
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # 512
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # 1024 
       ], dtype=uint8)
```

You can then continue the process again for larger numbers:

```
a = np.array([0,1,2,254,255,256,257,512,1024,65535,65536,65537])[:,None]

np.c_[np.unpackbits((a>>16).astype(np.uint8), axis=1),
      np.unpackbits((a>>8).astype(np.uint8), axis=1),
      np.unpackbits(a.astype(np.uint8), axis=1),
      ]

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

Generic approach to generate all numbers from 1 to n-1:

```
def numpy_packbits(n):
    a = np.arange(n)[:,None]
    #N = int(np.ceil(np.log2(n)/8))
    #M = int(np.ceil(np.log2(n)))
    M = (n-1).bit_length()
    N = -(M // -8)
    return np.hstack([np.unpackbits((a>>(8*x)).astype(np.uint8), axis=1)
                      for x in range(N-1, -1, -1)])[:, -M:]
```

##### Timings

[image]

Comment: @nocomment my latest solution goes up to 24 bits (~16M), isn't that enough? ;)

Comment: Fine let me update it

Comment: Here it is, see update

Comment: Oops, typo, copied a test version

Comment: The question doesn't specify details on that. Anyway you can slice to the desired number of bus as shown in my first code.

Comment: I doubt one can generate 2**56+1 items ;) but sure the bit_length is more precise for large numbers. I updated to add the slice

Comment: Added a graph of timings

Comment: Nice. One more thing: "from 1 to n-1" should say "from 0"

Answer (score 1):

Two fast ways that build the array for i+1 bits from the array for i bits.

Benchmark for 20 bits (with other solutions slightly adjusted so we all do the same thing):

```
  40 ms  binary_counting_1
  16 ms  binary_counting_2
1202 ms  Andrej_Kesely
4668 ms  Arne
  79 ms  mozway
```

Code:

```py
def binary_counting_1(n, dtype):
    a = np.array([[]], dtype=dtype)
    for i in range(n):
        a = np.vstack(
            [np.c_[np.zeros(2**i, dtype), a],
             np.c_[np.ones(2**i, dtype), a]]
        )
    return a


def binary_counting_2(n, dtype):
    a = np.zeros((2**n, n), dtype)
    for i in range(n):
        m = 2**i
        a[m:2*m, -i:] = a[:m, -i:]
        a[m:2*m, ~i] = 1
    return a


def Andrej_Kesely(n, dtype):
    return np.fromiter(product([0, 1], repeat=n), dtype=(dtype, n))


def Arne(N_DIGITS, dtype):
    return np.array([list(format(i, 'b').zfill(N_DIGITS)) 
                for i in range(2 ** N_DIGITS)], dtype=dtype)


def mozway(n, dtype):
    n = 2**n
    a = np.arange(n)[:,None]
    M = (n-1).bit_length()
    N = -(M // -8)
    return np.hstack([np.unpackbits((a>>(8*x)).astype(dtype), axis=1)
                      for x in range(N-1, -1, -1)])[:, -M:]


funcs = binary_counting_1, binary_counting_2, Andrej_Kesely, Arne, mozway

import numpy as np
from time import time
from itertools import product

n, dtype = 20, 'uint8'
expect = funcs[0](n, dtype)
for _ in range(3):
    for f in funcs:
        t0 = time()
        result = f(n, dtype)
        print(f'{(time()-t0)*1e3 :4.0f} ms ', f.__name__)
        assert (result == expect).all()
        del result
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVRNj9MwED1x8U_gNLfaUdJtuhyqSl0JCQmtUHuBWxRFbutsDYkT2Q60RfBHuOwFfhS_hnE-t82uiNQ2nXkzfm_mJb_-lCd7KNTj4-_KpsHi76vXe5HCViquT8muqJSV6iEJqfJhb0-lYEsCeHFYgSqnXGt-olEUx2161YBqTFpokCAVaK4eBFVt6ZPyr8by3Rfah90VYXyXuO-z0IWhc8-T3dk-8Ni_QEOPLpQYg-Me3FDSwlZaASeEPCdz_oLMhonrjnnFOsz_VOZY7RgNsqN8OfdyHwK5jDHJo2X7Zwz5KR0ifI72W7XX4nPyQRiRna4pt1hkneoil1ZoWupiX-0sjWY-hLgpLUrB7aoXsqL1j5PGuiO0EnSTvLt_f__p40sHtNvPpLEUx5BzS3H6k-2ETc-pzLK-AWNwubXx3ObgedDjr-3UkMqL8zc-EqyaKatLX7bLiJb-Bp3RzHeNSaqCkE230iaZUA_2QJstbjAV0DXc3ECwYFc6D41NncsqVeItlqMd-N0dXXhHxqbcOD60991RmlXIRpIH4cdB-CYI0QL1h8WOLwRr9AMhaaV2BmmNnkV_7Fv_0hN-vT-_HRghMi8LbUFVeXkCblATceYAK3MBbdLdN1HnGVsUmelSrX8I6SbvJo5emlRS2cWEiGMpdhaDNeVoFg8rIk5tMqi9bZfmwqkL1yXDI2Nn2MZRocP4tDBVVrd_0rdLlho50HTynTZVgZ0xLxS3sHwznaU_IDcw8SGdJoniuUiSoZIbgzqBdu1X0OjAdaJ1B9xeZC2F5hXZvim7N-Y_)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use `itertools.product`:

```py
from itertools import product

arr = np.fromiter(product([0, 1], repeat=4), dtype=(int, 4))
print(arr)
```

Prints:

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain Python approach:

```
import numpy as np

N_DIGITS = 4

print(np.array([list(format(i, 'b').zfill(N_DIGITS)) 
                for i in range(2 ** N_DIGITS)], dtype='int8'))
```

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```